# angular - How to do dynamic default checked checkboxes with reactive forms

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-reactive-forms

I have a edit profile form. for has dynamic checkbox. if user updated the check box once then it should checked default.

Here is my ts file...

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApplicantsService } from '@app/services/applicants.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  myForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
 
  userid: any;
  
  skills: any;
  experience: any;
  applicant_skills: any;
  profile: any;
  states: any;
  cities: any;
  profilePicture: any;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private applicantsService: ApplicantsService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.userid = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).user_id;

    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      userid: [''],
      first_name: new FormControl({value: null, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
      last_name: new FormControl({value: null, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
      email: new FormControl({value: null, disabled: true}, Validators.required),
      mobile: ['', Validators.required],
      state: ['', Validators.required],
      city: ['', Validators.required],
      skills: this.formBuilder.array([], [Validators.required]),
    });
    
    this.applicantsService.getProfile(this.userid).subscribe( res => {
      this.profile = res.data[0];
      this.myForm.patchValue(this.profile); 
    })

    this.applicantsService.getApplicantskills(this.userid).subscribe( res => 
    {
      if(res && res.data)
      {
        this.applicant_skills = res.data;
        
        
      }
    })


  }


  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() { return this.myForm.controls; }

 


  onCheckboxChange(e) {
    const checkArray: FormArray = this.myForm.get('skills') as FormArray;

    if (e.target.checked) {
      checkArray.push(new FormControl(e.target.value));
    } else {
      let i: number = 0;
      checkArray.controls.forEach((item: FormControl) => {
        if (item.value == e.target.value) {
          checkArray.removeAt(i);
          return;
        }
        i++;
      });
    }
  }

  onSubmit()
  {
      this.submitted = true;

      // stop here if form is invalid
      if (this.myForm.invalid) {
        console.log(this.myForm)
        return;
      }

      console.log("this.myForm.value", this.myForm.value);
      
  }

}
```

Here is my html page.

```
<!-- Spinner -->
<ngx-spinner></ngx-spinner>

<section id="profile-form" class="bg-grey">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12">
          
          <h1 class="text-center">Update your profile</h1>

          <div class="form p-md-6">

              
              <form  [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group d-none">
                        <input type="text"  formControlName="userid" value={{userid}}>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="linkedin">First Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="first_name" placeholder="First Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="linkedin">Email ID</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" placeholder="Email ID">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <label for="lastname">Cellphone Number</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="mobile" placeholder="Cellphone Number" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.mobile.errors }" required>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.mobile.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                            <div *ngIf="f.mobile.errors.required">This field is required</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                

                  
                  <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="button-group-pills text-center col-md-12" data-toggle="buttons">

                        <label class="btn btn-default" *ngFor="let skill of skills">
                            <input type="checkbox" formArrayName="skills" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" value={{skill.id}} [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.skills.errors }" required>
                            <div>{{skill.skill}}</div>
                        </label>
                        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.skills.errors" class="error">
                            <div *ngIf="f.skills.errors.required">This field is required</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      
                  </div>



                  <div class="form-row justify-content-center text-center pt-4 pb-2">
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-apply px-4">save profile</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
              
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Please help .........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You toggle `[checked]` value by checking if the current value is in the `checkArray` array

Include this in your input field

`[checked]="checkArray.includes(skill.id)"`

So your input becomes

```
    <input type="checkbox" formArrayName="skills" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" [checked]="checkArray.includes(skill.id)
 value={{skill.id}} [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.skills.errors }" required>
```

UPDATE

The above would work if you're pushing only the `id` of the skill into the array. But since you are pushing the entire `skill` object you can check for the object instead.

`[checked]="checkArray.includes(skill)"`

```
   <input type="checkbox" formArrayName="skills" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" [checked]="checkArray.includes(skill)
 value={{skill.id}} [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.skills.errors }" required>
```

Comment: not working... 
My checkArray structure is look like this,
`
CheckedArray = [
0: {
id: 1,
skill: "item1"
},
1: {
id: 2,
skill: "item2"
},
]
`

Comment: I have updated the answer to suit your condition. Let me if that works, if it doesn't I can show you a solution using pipe instead. Cheers

Comment: it's showing ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Comment: Oh I see that your array variable is static and is cleared every time you the check box changes. You can declare checkArray before the constructor like so `checkArray: any = []` and then in your `onCheckboxChange(e)` func then call `this.checkArray` instead of declaring a const `checkArray`. Let me know if this is clear

Answer (score 1):

Sadique, I suppose you want that your "skills" was an array of values. I don't find the SO where I used ngModel inside a ReactiveForms to mannage a list of checkBox. The most closer is [this another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63797930/get-multiple-checkbox-value-as-an-array-in-angular/63799360#63799360)

The idea is that you has NOT a FormArray, just a FormControl, and you use [(ngModel)] to give value to the formControl. yes a FormControl can store an Array, and yes a FormControl exist even you has no input in .html

```html
    <label class="btn btn-default" *ngFor="let skill of skills">
       <input type="checkbox" 
          [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"
          <!--see that "is checked" if in the array you has the value-->
          [ngModel]="(myForm.get('skills').value || []).indexOf(skill.id)>=0" 
          <!--when change, we call to the function-->
          (ngModelChange)="onChange($event,skill.id)" >
           <div>{{skill.skill}}</div>
    </label>
```

And

```
  onChange(checked: boolean, id: number) {
    
    const control = this.myForm.get("skills"); //get the control
    let value = control.value || [];       //get the value, if null an empty array
    if (checked && value.indexOf(id) < 0)  //if we checked and it's not in the array
      value = [...value, id].sort((a, b) =>    //concatenate the value and sort
        this.skills.findIndex(f => f.id == a) >
        this.skills.findIndex(f => f.id == b)? 1: -1
      );
    if (!checked) value = value.filter(x => x != id);  //if not checked remove it

    control.setValue(value.length ? value : null);  //finally set value
                          //see that is nothing selected, give value null
                          //this make that we can use Validators.required
  }
```

See [the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-o1japm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks for your answer... 
My actual issue is, I have to make my checkboxes as checked dynamically...

If anyone selected 2 items and saved, then it should checked all time...

I expecting you got issue..

Thanks

Comment: when you create the Control you can give value, e.g. `myForm.get('skills').setValue([1,3])`, or when you create the form control:`myForm=new FormGroup({skill:new FormControl([1],Validators.required})`. If in your "profile" the value of "skills" is an array, should work your `this.myForm.patchValue(this.profile);` what's the value or your "profile"?